# C# - cannot attach file to an email

Tags: c#, excel, email, service

I have a service that creates an Excel file and sends it by email.

This service works correctly on a test server but on a production server I have a bug - there is strange file in attachments without extension with name like this `=utf-8B0J3QtdC0YDQvtGB0YLQsNCy0LvQtdC9` and the same content inside instead of an Excel file.

There is my sending method. I suppose that there are no troubles in my code.

```
public static void SendEmail(string subject, string body, string recipients, Attachment attachment = null)
    {
        string mailServer = Settings.Default.MailServer;

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(Settings.Default.MailSender, recipients);
        foreach (string address in Settings.Default.MailCopyTo.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
                message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(address));
        }
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = body;
        message.Subject = subject;

        if(attachment != null)
            message.Attachments.Add(attachment);


        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
        var AuthenticationDetails = new NetworkCredential(Settings.Default.MailLogin, Settings.Default.MailPassword);
        client.Credentials = AuthenticationDetails;
        client.Send(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in the .NET Framework with attachments the file name of which is longer than 41 unicode characters.

I also had the same problem and fixed it by truncating the file name to 40 characters. What I did:

1. Get file extension
2. Get file name without extension
3. Shorten file name to `40 - extension.Length` characters
4. Add extension

I quote from an answer in [an MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67414337-19a6-4128-b1a0-212404cc2cb1/bug-in-systemnetmail-net-4?forum=netfxnetcom):

> Yes we are aware of this problem and have already addressed it for
>   future releases. [...]
>
> In .NET 4.0 SmtpClient now implements the RFC line length limits (76
>   chars).  This required extensive changes to the encoding process and
>   we have uncovered a few issues like the one you describe.
>
> In your case, yes, there is an issue with non-ascii attachment names
>   that would be encoded to more than 41 utf-8 bytes
>   (Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(fileName);).  In this scenario the names
>   are encoded twice and may have extra line breaks in them.  The only
>   known workaround is to limit the length of non-ascii file names.

Comment: All I meant to say is that we should encourage OPs to include more detail in their questions and to verify any suspicions using comments, before making (educated) guesses using answers, as updates from OP may invalidate answers or even make questions obsolete (case in point: see duplicate).

Comment: While I agree with you on that, I didn't really get this message from your original comments. Now I understand what you were trying to say. Of course the OP could have googled first (that's how I found the cause of the problem and the solution, too).